# d3 using this when multiple divs call a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scenario where data in different divs will call the same function. I need to know what div the mouse is currently in.

d3.select(this) returns one div and then the other as they both call this function.

Is there a d3 function that returns what element the mouse is currently located in (i.e thats not d3.select(this))?

Comment: `this` will refer to the element on which the event is triggered inside a handler function. It sounds like this is what you want. Can't really tell you more without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is that I have a function with this in it that is called by two handlers, so they both return their elements. I only need the element that the mouse is currently in. Maybe this is impossible and I need to change approaches.

Comment: If two handlers call it then there's no single element that the mouse is over, is there?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. Thanks again.